# Recursive function to calculate time complexity

Tags: c++, recursion, time-complexity, trie

I'm learning to calculate time complexity.  I can calculate a simple case but I wonder how to calculate the time complexity of a recursive function. In normal function, it's clearly done knowing how many comparison, swaps,. . . In recursive function, I don't know how to count all cases that can happen because when I write a recursive function, I am basing it on some theory like "thinking recursively" that assumes that my function already works ... so I always confuse when calculating the time of the recursive function. The example function below that I wrote:

```
 #define MAX 26 // represent 26 letter in alphabet

//--------- TRIE STRUCTURE-----------
struct Trie {
    Trie* m_arr[MAX];   // leaves 

    bool m_isend;   // check that leaf is the end of a word

    string m_path;  // store path from root to that leaf

    Trie() {  //constructor

        m_path = "";  // path <empty>

        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {  // initialize leaves <NULL>
            m_arr[i] = NULL;
        }

        m_isend = false; // check the end of word <false>
    }
};
//-------------------


//-------INIT NODE---------
Trie* getNode() {  // Dynamic a node
    return(new Trie);
}
//-------------------

//----------INSERT WORD-------------
void insertWord(Trie* root, string str, string path = "") { // insert a word into trie (root<trie>, str<string want to insert>, path<store path of parent>)

    if (str.length() == 0) {  // if data is inputed has length equal to 0 -> return 
        return;
    }

    if (!root) {  // if the trie that we want to add new word is empty, we will init it with NULL leaves
        root = getNode();
    }

    if (!root->m_arr[str[0] - 'a']) {  // the leaf that we want to jump to is NULL we have to init it 
        root->m_arr[str[0] - 'a'] = getNode();
    }

    if (root->m_arr[str[0] - 'a']->m_path.length() == 0) { // the leaf that we want to jump to has empty path -
                                                           // we have to add its parent's path to its path 
        root->m_arr[str[0] - 'a']->m_path += path;
        root->m_arr[str[0] - 'a']->m_path.push_back(str[0]);
    }

    if (str.length() > 1) { //if lenght of word still great than 1, countinous with properties leaf
        insertWord(root->m_arr[str[0] - 'a'], str.substr(1), root->m_arr[str[0] - 'a']->m_path);
    }
    else { //else finish process by turn flag (end of a word)
        
        root->m_arr[str[0] - 'a']->m_isend = true;
    }
}
//---------------
```

hope you can explain to me how to calculate time complexity of above function?

Comment: You can calculate the complexity by "thinking recursively" and assuming you already know the complexity of the recursive calls ;) If a function `f` is defined by `void f(int n) { doSomeWork(n); if (n > 12) { f(n - 7); } }`, then the complexity of `f(n)` is the sum of the complexity of `doSomeWork(n)` and the complexity of `f(n-7)`.

Comment: Remember that recursion is really just another kind of loop. In fact, any recursive function can be implemented using a stack or a queue rather than function calls. The complexity will be a function of the work done on an individual dataum and (potentially) the number of items to be processed.